# UIImageView in UICollectionViewCell in UITableViewCell bug

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

The settings for the `UICollectionView` were defined using IB (ie scroll direction: horizontal, etc), and was embedded in `UITableViewCell` using IB.

`UICollectionViewCell` displays, images display, however, images are stacked on top of one another, instead of one image per one `cell` with fidelity.

[image: images stacked on top of one another]

I made individual `UIImageView` for each picture as instance variables, and same occurred using if and `switch` statements in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` message.

Since IB was used, it may be a stretch to identify the bug, however, would you please help to identify the bug in case it is obvious from the code? Thanks.

```
@implementation AccountTableViewCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state

    imageArray = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"image1.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image2.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image3.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image4.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"image5.png"]];

    self.oCollectionView.dataSource = self;
    [self.oCollectionView setFrame:self.contentView.frame];
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.oCollectionView];
    self.oCollectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.oCollectionView reloadData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return imageArray.count;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"accountCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:iv];
    [iv setFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
    iv.image = imageArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you keep on adding an `UIImageView` to the `cell` each time it's dequeued.

Instead, you should subclass the `UICollectionViewCell` (let's call it "MYCollectionViewCell", add a `UIImageView` to the `cell` subclass in the `storyboard` and set the `UIImageView` as an outlet on the subclass.

Then, within `cellForItemAtIndexPath`, set that `imageView's` image like so:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MyCollectionViewCell* cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"accountCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```